# Smooth polygon in polar plot- R package

Tags: r, polygon, smoothing, polar-coordinates

In R package,
is there any way to smoothen the polygon in a polar.plot?

I tried to use the splines, but could not find a way to insert the curved line in the polar.plot..

(I am a begginer in R programming)

Comment: Need code that starts out with `library(...)` that loads the right package and then builds some data and  a polygon. There could be many R packages with a function by that name.

Comment: I have the polygon of my data by using polar.plot of plotrix library, but i can not make it smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I know that mathematically with polar plotting you can get smoothed polygons. An example here is for the square if you plot: 1 + Sin[4*x]/20 from 0 to 2 $\pi$ you will get a smoothed square. Change 4 to 5 and adjust the other constants by interpolation and you may find yourself happy.